# How to change the record created as a one-to-one relation to itself Entity Framework 7 (ASP.NET Core)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I use `EntityFramework 7 RC1` in the project `ASP.NET 5 MVC 6 RC 1`

I do not work change roles (each role has a parent). Below is a simplified example of what I'm trying to do. This code runs successfully and does not cause errors.

```
                var roleDb = roleManager.FindByNameAsync("UserRole").Result;
                var searchRoleDb = roleManager.FindByNameAsync("AdminRole").Result;

                if (roleDb != null)
                {
                    roleDb.DateEdit = DateTime.Now;
                    if (searchRoleDb != null)
                    {
                        roleDb.Parent = searchRoleDb;
                    }
                    context.Entry(roleDb).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
```

But ParentId field in the database remains null.

```
public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
{
    ...

    public string ParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationRole Parent { get; set; }

    ...
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, string>
    {
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);

            builder.Entity<ApplicationRole>()
                .HasOne(c => c.Parent)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(c => c.ParentId);
        }
    }
```

I have also successfully changed the other data in the database, as well as the successful use of data migration.

I can not just change the value ParentId.

Comment: This is most likely because your getting the role via the RoleManager and then trying to save the changes with your context. Use the RoleManager to update the role `await roleManager.UpdateAsync(roleDb)`

Comment: Also its worth pointing out that the way you're calling _roleManager.FindByNameAsync_ could potentially cause deadlocks in your application. See [here](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) for details

Comment: @lawst Yes, I constantly meet the information, but to the end I can not understand.

Comment: @lawst The code in question works for me when deploying ASP.NET Core applications.
I replaced `roleManager` synchronous methods of `context`. This will prevent the problem described by you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my initial comment, you should use the asp.net Identity RoleManager class when making changes to the role since you're using it to retrieve the roles as part of the change. You could use your context to do it manually/directly but this is effectively bypassing asp.net identity. Here is an updated version of your original sample using RoleManager to perform the update:

```
public async Task UpdateRole()
{
    var roleDb = await roleManager.FindByNameAsync("UserRole");
    var searchRoleDb = await roleManager.FindByNameAsync("AdminRole");

    if (roleDb != null)
    {
        roleDb.DateEdit = DateTime.Now;
        if (searchRoleDb != null)
        {
            roleDb.Parent = searchRoleDb;
        }

        await roleManager.UpdateAsync(roleDb);
    }
}
```

I've also updated the FindByNameAsync calls to use "await" rather than ".Result" to avoid the potential deadlock issue I mentioned. However for this to work the method signature must return a Task and include the "async" modifier. For help with the asynchronous stuff I recommend starting [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx)

**Edit**

Based on the comment with regards to seeding, I normally seed my roles like this:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyDbContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(MyDbContext context)
    {
        SeedRoles(context);
    }

    private static void SeedRoles(MyDbContext context)
    {
        var manager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context));
        CreateRoleIfNotExists(manager, "Role1");
        CreateRoleIfNotExists(manager, "Role2");
    }

    private static void CreateRoleIfNotExists(RoleManager<IdentityRole> manager, string role)
    {
        if (!manager.RoleExists(role)
        {
            manager.Create(new IdentityRole(role));
        }
    }
}
```

You'll need to update the code with your Context, User and Role classes as I've just used the defaults.

There is no need to explicitly save the changes as this is done by the DbContext class when the call to Seed() returns/completes. With this approach there are no async calls so you don't need to worry about any of the issues I mentioned with regards to that.

Comment: `UpdateRole` is part of a class `RoleSeedData`, and `RoleSeedData` called in `Startup.cs/Configure(...)` which is synchronous. I need to call a method on how `RoleSeedData.Initialize(...).Wait ()`? Or should I change the `Configure` method is asynchronous?

Comment: @Kolya_Net I've updated my answer for seeding. You don't need to make any async calls with the approach I've provided.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the roleManager uses a different context than you use for database modifications. You should get the role through the context and modify it then.

```
            var roleDb = context.Set<IdentityRole>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "UserRole");
            var searchRoleDb = context.Set<IdentityRole>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "AdminRole");

            if (roleDb != null)
            {
                roleDb.DateEdit = DateTime.Now;
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
```

Comment: Tell me please, what is the difference between this code `context.Set<IdentityRole>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "UserRole");` and this `context.Roles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "UserRole");`?

Comment: When I give an example I use the method because I don't know how your DbContext is setup. It is possible that the roles is just a getter that returns the dbset of IdentityRole